# Adding batch script to Windows 8 context menu

Tags: windows, batch-file

I saw some other questions about this here, but still got nothing working for what I want.

I want to right click the empty space of a folder, and see a menu for executing a batch file **for the current folder**.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\treeFiles]
@="Execute treeFiles"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\treeFiles\command]
@="C:\treeFiles.bat \"%V\""
@="C:\\treeFiles.bat -d \"\"%V\"\""
```

With the above, I can only see the item when I right-click a folder (not the empty space), and the batch will execute relative to it's self path, not the current folder.

Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\treeFiles]
@="&Execute treeFiles"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\shell32.dll,71"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\treeFiles\command]
@="C:\\treeFiles.bat \"%V\""
```

Comment: By the way, do you know why my "right-click on folder" version is executing from the batch file root dir, instead of the selected dir which I'm clicking on?

Comment: @TomBrito Yes, I do. It's because you've specified a `NoWorkingDirectory` string value in your REG file [which starts the script with the default working directory of `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32`](http://superuser.com/a/704819/167187).