# Python script won't run from the context menu

Tags: python, windows, registry, contextmenu

[Submitted to superuser two days ago, but nobody could answer it, so reposting here.]

Working on the basis of [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/444726/windows-how-to-add-batch-script-action-to-right-click-menu) (and [this follow-up post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946581/adding-batch-script-to-windows-8-context-menu)), I've tried adding a python script (which I've added to the path and so on, so that I can run it from the command line everywhere in the system) to the context menu, like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\get_abs]
@="&Get Abstracts"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\shell32.dll,71"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\get_abs\command]
@="C:\\cmdtools\\get_abs.py"
```

However, I get a strange error message when I try to run it.

[image]

To be clear, I have successfully run this script from the command line (using powershell, in case it matters) in the folder in which I'm trying to run it from the context menu.

Comment: I believe the `command` key needs to point to an actual executable, e.g. `.exe` file. Try it with the path to your Python interpreter followed by the script path.

Comment: You with a space in between, with the script path like an argument?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Might be worth trying anyway. You might also need `%1` for the file being passed in (which would go at the end, with another space before it).

Comment: That did it! Write your answer as an answer and I'll mark it right.

Comment: By the way, I'm totally fascinated by 6502 assem. lang.! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python scripts aren't natively executable by Windows; it's complaining that you didn't specify an `.exe` file. That's easy though, you just specify `python.exe`. Follow that up with the path to your script and then a `%1` -- this is a placeholder for the path to the clicked file.  To allow your command to work with paths with spaces in them, surround the `%1` with quote marks. Putting it all together, we get:

```
C:\path\to\python.exe C:\path\to\your\script.py "%1"
```

BTW, a handy utility for managing context menus is [Fast Explorer](http://www.tucows.com/preview/375525/Fast-Explorer).

Comment: The script itself doesn't take any arguments (it works on all the files in the folder it's run in), so I don't need the "%1," but thanks for mentioning that.